# remove inverted commas from python string

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have a very annoying string formatting issue. I tried different approaches but i seem to be lost.
This is my expected output: ["aa","b","c","dd"].

Sample code:

```
mylist = ['b','c']
mylisttmp = ','.join('"{0}"'.format(x) for x in mylist)
finalstr='"aa"' +","+"{}".format(mylisttmp) +","+'"dd"'
print([finalstr])

OUTPUT:['"aa","b","c","dd"']   #How to get rid of the end quotes,which is causing issues?
```

I did a lot of string splitting, joining etc but I am going round and round the same issue.
I intended to use the formatted output with a tkinter property, as follows:

```
myComboBox['values']= ["aa","b","c","dd"]
```

Please direct me. Thank you

Comment: If you print a list, the strings will be quoted (using whatever quotes Python thinks is appropriate). If you just want to print your finalstr with square brackets around it, how about `print('[' + finalstr + ']')` ?

Comment: You don't actually want a string.  You want a list of four strings.  That's very different.  I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually want a string at all.  You want a list that contains four strings.

```
mylist = ['b','c']
finalset = ["aa"] + mylist + ["dd"]
print(finalset)
```

**Output**

```
>>> print(finalset)
['aa', 'b', 'c', 'dd']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

I mean you already are appending `aa` and `dd`, then why not just add open and close square brackets with them?

```
mylist = ['b','c']
mylisttmp = ','.join('"{0}"'.format(x) for x in mylist)
finalstr='["aa"' +","+"{}".format(mylisttmp) +","+'"dd"]'
print(finalstr)
```

**Output**

```
["aa","b","c","dd"]
```

Comment: Thank u all for your responses. However, i am now getting the following error with the provided solution:```_tkinter.TclError: list element in quotes followed by "dd" instead of space```

Comment: @codeheadache Where in `tkinter` are you using this.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially two fundamental misunderstandings of what you're seeing.

1. The single quotes that you're talking about (the ones you want to get rid of) are just the interpreter telling you that this object is a string. But you knew that, because you literally created it as a string.

and

2. The python interpreter accepts single and double quotes as string delimiters, but will display strings as delimited by single quotes. So when you want `["a","b"]`, but can probably only ever get `['a','b']`, you see that as an error, but in fact they're the same.

So in your case, what you probably want is something like `['aa','b','c','dd']`. Don't mess around with the string formatting at all.

Comment: Wow such a simple issue with such deep fundamentals. Certainly you cleared a fundamental error and flawed concept. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

```
print(f'["aa",{mylisttmp},"dd"]')
```